# Is $\mathrm d(PV)$ the same with work received OR produced?

Tags: thermodynamics, work, conventions

When I write energy conservation in thermodynamics problems, I write the internal energy before, the pressure energy before (so these two are the enthalpy) and then I add/substract the work and heat done, and equal to the same quantities after. Is this correct? Or is work equal to the pressure energy difference? I am a bit confused. Let's say we add work to the system, then $$U_1+P_1V_1+W=U_2+P_2V_2$$ Is that correct? Now let's say work is *done* by the system, then $$U_1+P_1V_1=U_2+P_2V_2+W$$Is that correct? I am afraid I may calculate the work twice.

In other words, I see $\Delta(U)=Q-W$, is that complete? I think it doesn't take into account the pressure energy of the system. But I see it online as 2nd Thermodynamic Law! Instead I think $\Delta(U)+\Delta(PV)=Q-W$ is complete. Any ideas?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thermodynamics+work+conventions

Comment: can you explain in simple words what is the difference between dU=Q-W and dU+d(PV)=Q-W? I think the first is only correct when there is no work done by external factor and the W is the work done by the system. While in the latter W is the work done by external factor of the system? In other words when dU=Q-W true and when dH=Q-W true?

Comment: The difference is that the former is true (aka **1st** law of thermodynamics, known for ~150 years) and the latter is false. The best way to cure confusion is understanding. That's what FreezingFire is trying to provide.

Answer (score 1):

The equation $\Delta U = Q - W$ is complete in itself.

The confusion arises in the definition of enthalpy. We tend to think that the "pressure energy" $PV$ and the work done by the system $W$ are somehow *different*. But the fact is that there isn't a well defined physical meaning to the $PV$ term. It is confusing because when we add $U$ and $PV$, we think that the $PV$ part is somehow missing in the $U$ and so needs to be added. That is not actually the case. Actually, *we **add** it to **remove** a term that is already present, which is the **work done on the system***.

How? Well we must understand first that enthalpy is a quantity that is meant to be measured at constant pressure. It was defined in a way, so that at constant pressure, it would be a state function, and also easy to measure, since most chemical reactions are carried out at constant pressure, i.e. the atmospheric pressure. We first define $H=U+PV$. Now, we differentiate it and get:
$$\mathrm dH = \mathrm dU + P\,\mathrm dV + V\,\mathrm dP$$
Now, at constant pressure, $\mathrm dP=0$. Integrating the remaining part, we get:
$$\Delta H = \Delta U + P \Delta V$$
Now, see that if we replace $\Delta U$ by $Q-W$, remembering that at constant pressure $W=P\Delta V$, we see that:
$$\Delta H = Q - P\Delta V + P\Delta V = Q$$
The above equation shows that adding the term $P\Delta V$ removes the work term from the internal energy change $\Delta U$, leaving the *heat supplied* term $Q$.

That cleared out of the way, now if you want to calculate the change in enthalpy, you will write:
$$H_2 - H_1 = U_2 - U_1 + PV_2 - PV_1$$
and thus we arrive at the correct equation:
$$-H_1 + U_1 + PV_1 = -H_2 + U_2 + PV_2$$
remembering that the pressure remains constant. Clearly there is no work term in the above equation.

Comment: What do you mean by "we cannot always get the simplified form mentioned in the question"?

Comment: @L.Levrel I mean that the simple equation $\Delta H = \Delta U + P \Delta V$ is not always valid (this is the equation mentioned in the question, in another form) unless the simplifying assumption is made that the pressure is constant.

Comment: I'm confused, because I see no such equation (or equivalent) in the question. All I see is $ΔH=ΔU+Δ(PV)$.

Comment: @L.Levrel You are right in your confusion! I will correct it and make it clearer...

Comment: @L.Levrel See if the answer is clear now. I had messed up my equations a little. Thank you for your interest!

Comment: Better! But 1)"work done on the gas": the system needn't be a gas. 2) You have the wrong signs in the last equations :-) ; you could remove the last paragraph altogether, it doesn't add much.

Comment: Ah! Messed up again! I have corrected now! The last paragraph is to show the correct versions of OP's first two equations, so I would like to leave it there... Thanks again! :)

Comment: Can you sum up in a single line? No need for detailed explanations and maths. Is dU=Q-W the correct or dU+d(PV)=Q-W? I tend to think the latter is more complete. The first is only when the work is done BY the system? While the latter is when the work is done by external factor? In other words when dU=Q-W true and when dH=Q-W true?

Comment: @ergon $dU = Q-W$ is correct and $dH = dQ + V\,dP$ is correct. The answer offers an explanation for why this isn't as expected.

Comment: I am not satisfied with your answer at all to be honest. And I never mentioned dH=dQ+VdP, I mentioned dH=Q-W, so it would be nice to see your answer on what I specifically asked. Anyway, from the little I could understand from your very verbose and incomprehensible explanation, you are just saying that dU=Q-W is only true for dP=0? Or what? You really don't make much sense to me, I see you are trying to tell something but I don't know what. Can you explain it with one sentence? I am sure the answer is few words instead of your 4 paragraph text.

Comment: In every process, we have initial internal energy and initial pressure energy (ignoring potential and kinetic energy, etc). At the end we have different internal energy and different pressure energy. The above simply means that we have different enthalpy. During the process, Q may be added or substracted from the system, which we add to the equation accordingly. Now, also W can be added or substracted from the system.

Comment: The question is simple, do we add that accordingly to the equation or it is already considered in delta(PV)? (PLEASE DONT distinguish between P=constant or V=constant, or whatever, because you only make things more complicated than needed, since the energy conservation should work in ANY case). If it is NOT considered in delta(PV) and needs to be added, then how do books write dU=Q-W, without considering delta(PV)? Is it just a unique condition that each equation is for or what?

Comment: Sorry to be unable to clear your confusion! Let me try once more. Forget enthalpy. The equation $\Delta U = Q - W$ is *always correct*. Whether you do work on the system, whether the pressure-volume term increases or decreases, *that* is the valid equation. *And, very important*, the work done is, *in any case*, $\int P\,\mathrm dV$. I think your root of confusion is you are thinking the work done and $\int P\,\mathrm dV$ terms to be different things. They are not.

Comment: If dU=Q-W is always true, when we have an adiabatic expansion, so Q=0 and W is something, we must have some dU? It is NOT possible to have dU=0 in such situation?

Comment: Right, dU=-W if Q=0.

Comment: So what does dH then equals to? Only Q? So if I know the dH of a process, that equals to Q transferred into/out of the system? Even if there is Work done by/on to the system? Even if pressure is not constant?

Comment: Also, this NASA webpage proves you  wrong: https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/thermo1f.html They say  that dH=Q-W. (if you ignore kinetic energy)

Comment: No, it doesn't. In fact, it proves our statement correct. It has explicitly said $\Delta U=Q-W$. Also, the page says "total specific enthalpy", which is way different from just "enthalpy". And the equation is $\Delta h = q - w_\text{sh}$. The work term is "shaft work", not the one i mean. I simply mean the "total work done by the gas in any form".

Comment: The equation for "enthalpy" is: $\mathrm dH=\mathrm dU+P\,\mathrm dV+V\,\mathrm dP$. If we are considering an ideal gas (with no net velocity), then we can write $P\,\mathrm dV+V\,\mathrm dP=nR\,\mathrm dT$. Integrating, we get: $\Delta H=\Delta U+nR\Delta T$, where $n$ is the number of moles of gas (assumed constant), and $T$ is the absolute temperature. For an arbitrary system, we need more information to integrate the equation for enthalpy.

Comment: And, for any arbitrary system, if pressure is constant, then we can write $\Delta H = \Delta U + P\Delta V$ as i already said in my answer. Summary: $\Delta U = Q-W$ is always correct, and for finding the expression for enthalpy, we need to know more information about the type of process the system undergoes. The $\mathrm dH$ can equal a number of things in different conditions.