# Why expansion work, $pdV$, is considered to be zero in nozzle?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, work, volume

Why $pdV$ work considered to be zero for flow of gas, say ideal gas, at low mach number through a converging adiabatic nozzle? [though total enthalpy remains constant, static enthalpy does change.] [Consider an element of gas going through the system, ie when using Lagrangian approach.]
Gas does expand in the nozzle ryt?

UPDATE:
A part of the answer can be found here: [Why does boundary work in throttling process is zero when change in volume is not?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/443839/)
[The part answer: When considering a fluid element going through a nozzle, it does expand, but it does not say if the element does expansion work. (There is no expansion work when considering the Eulerian reference frame.)]

So, my updated question:

Is there PdV work done by the expansion of this element (OR is it like free expansion with PdV work as zero). Also,in addition to the PdV work, is there also Pressure work done to accelerate the element through the nozzle and so increase the kinetic energy of the system/element?

Comment: PdV work is boundary work associated with closed systems. The nozzle is an open system.

Comment: @BobD I am considering a element of fluid ('closed system') going through a nozzle

Comment: Then you're talking about flow work (VdP) work/

Comment: @BobD The fluid element expands as it goes through the nozzle, but we don't consider the PdV work..Why is that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does boundary work in throttling process is zero when change in volume is not?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/443839/)

Comment: @Chemomechanics Thank you. I have updated my question.

Comment: It's not a free expansion unless the external pressure $P$ is zero. The rest of your question doesn't appear to be grammatical, and I don't understand it. Try a search on this site of, for example, `"flow work" is:question` or other relevant terms to find useful discussions of confusing points.

Comment: @Chemomechanics I found my own question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/717839/questions-about-flow-work-flow-energy. But it doesn't answer my current question completely as in that question The First law of Thermodynamics was considered applied to a stationary system! Here I also consider the Kinetic energy of the gas. Also, is the increase in Kinetic energy of the element dude to the pressure force acting on it considered as 'boundary work' done on the element or just 'work' done on the element?

Comment: Also, According to your previous, there is PdV work, and it is not free expansion when considering the fluid element going through the nozzle. But when considering an Eulerian approach there is no PdV work, as the boundary of the control volume (considered to be along the walls of the nozzle) doesn't change. How to understand this difference b/w the Lagrangian view point (which shows PdV work) and the eulerian view point (no PdV work)?

Comment: Are you familiar with the derivation of the open system (control volume) version of the 1st law of thermodynamics?

Comment: Internal PV work by one parcel on another does not count, because the work that parcel A does on parcel B is minus the work that parcel B does on parcel A. Only the work at the entrance and exit count, and these are lumped in with the entering and exiting enthalpy.

Comment: @ChetMiller But 'entrance and exit' mean you are talking in terms of control volume. I am looking at a particular fluid element. Do you mean that the PdV work done BY this element is intern done ON it from the 'fluid elements' all around it, and so net PdV work is zero? and so the only work being done ON the element is the pressure work that accelerates it?

Comment: And since this is a compressible gas...there is change in internal energy too. So totally the change in enthalpy?

Comment: You need to review the derivation.

Comment: @ChetMiller Can you please tell me how studying the Control Volume viewpoint derivation can help me understand the First law of TD applied to a NON-STATIONARY closed system?
That eq should be something like Q=U-W+KE+PE

Comment: @ChetMiller If the flow is taken to be adiabatic and the element is considered to be incomressible am i correct in my understanding that it it some part of work W  that causes the KE of the fluid to increase? If we consider instead that the element is compresisble, then it is Work done and also change in U that causes KE change?

Comment: No.  That is not the open system version of the 1st law of thermodynamics.  See Moran et al, Fundamentals of Engineering Thermodynamics.  It shows how to correctly convert the closed system version to the open system version.

Comment: No.  None of that is a correct rendering of the open system version.  Please articulate your detailed understanding of the derivation of the open system version from the closed system version.  You are not going to be able to solve any open system problems until you understand its derivation.

Comment: @ChetMiller My understanding is that to go from closed to open system add the Energy and work (U, KE , PV and PV work) coming in with the mass to the closed system energy eq which is dU = Q - W. So it is  dU = Q - W + (Work and Energy coming in with mass). Is this right ?

Comment: Helpful reference 1: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/601693/generalization-of-first-law-of-thermodynamics

ref 2: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/251355/is-mathrm-dpv-the-same-with-work-received-or-produced?rq=1

Comment: No, your equation for open system is not right.

Comment: @ChetMiller This is from the Text book by Moran et al on Thermodynamics.
[time rate of change
of the energy
contained within
the control volume at
time t} = [net rate at which
energy is being
transferred in
by heat transfer
at time t] - [net rate at which
energy is being
transferred out
by work at
time t] + [net rate of energy
transfer into the
control volume
accompanying
mass flow].
If the Flow work,PV, is separated from the work term in the above energy balance wont it be same as the eq I had in my Previous comment?

Comment: I made a mistake and wrote just 'coming in' and did not mention the 'going out' part is that what is wrong?

Comment: One more mistake I have used the notation for internal energy to mean total energy dU should be dE!